# Can't use bitcoin-cli commands, error message says "could not connect" from localhost

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I am simply trying to run `bitcoin-cli getinfo` on the same machine that my bitcoin node is running on (with `bitcoind -daemon`)

my bitcoin.conf file is as follows:

```
server='1'
rpcuser='username'
rpcpassword='password'
rpcport='8332'
```

The error message I receive is:

```
error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:0
```

This error is confusing me in two ways. First, my home network uses an Xfinity gateway (combined router/modem), and the local ip addresses look like `10.0.0.xx`, not `127.x.x.x`. Second, why is the error suggesting that it tried to connect on port 0? I have specified in bitcoin.conf that the rpc port is 8332. In this current state I can run a node, but I cannot make any rpc calls, rendering it useless for my purposes. Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- Bitcoin.conf does not use quotes in its definition of options. Your lines need to resemble `server=1` rather than `server='1'`. Your port number being zero is an artifact of this, which will not work as you need root permissions to bind to ports below 1024, which `bitcoind` does not and should not have.
- `127.0.0.1` is the [loopback address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) used when you're connecting to yourself, rather than a normal routable IP address. For safety's sake the RPC port is not by default enabled to bind to routable IP addresses, such as your 10.0.0.0/24 range. By default, it will only bind to `127.0.0.1` and subsequently only be accessible on the host it is running on.